# mysql: inner join with in and not in

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to pull rows from one table "articles" based on specific category tags from table "article_category_reference", to exclude articles that have a specific tag. I have this query right now:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.article_id,
    a.`title`,
    a.`text`,
    a.`date`
FROM
    `articles` a
INNER JOIN `article_category_reference` c ON
    a.article_id = c.article_id AND c.`category_id` NOT IN (54)
WHERE
    a.`active` = 1 
ORDER BY
    a.`date`
DESC
LIMIT 15
```

The problem is, it seems to grab rows even if they do have a row in the "article_category_reference" table where "category_id" matches "54". I've also tried it in the "where" clause and it makes no difference.

Keep in mind I'm using "NOT IN" as it may be excluding multiple tags.

SQL fiddle to show it: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2172/1

Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE `article_category_reference` (
  `ref_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `article_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `category_id` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

CREATE TABLE `articles` (
  `article_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `author_id` int(11) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
  `date` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `title` varchar(120) NOT NULL,
  `text` text CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 NOT NULL,
  `active` int(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '1'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to use an `EXISTS` clause:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    a.article_id,
    a.title,
    a.text,
    a.date
FROM articles a
WHERE
    a.active = 1 AND
    NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM article_category_reference c
                WHERE a.article_id = c.article_id AND c.category_id = 54)
ORDER BY
    a.date DESC
LIMIT 15;
```

The logical problem with your current approach of checking the category in the `WHERE` clause is that it is checking individual records.  You need to assert that *all* category records for a given article, in aggregate, do not match the category you wish to exclude.  An `EXISTS` clause, as I have written above, is one way to do it.  Using `GROUP BY` in a subquery is another way.

Comment: But, why isn't the original query not working ? Something missing ? Even shifting the condition to Where is not working.

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya LOL...I thought you were the OP, not someone else.

Comment: lol. But I have been tinkering with the fiddle given by OP and really surprised on why it isn't working! There is something being missed here

Comment: I can't even open that Fiddle.  The link is broken for me.

Comment: That works, thanks, I removed "DISTINCT" which made it slow.

Answer (score 0):

The NOT IN condition is evaluated for each joined rows. Since you have same article_id with multiple category_id-values, the ones that do match the NOT IN condition will get picked.

See [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/b2172/8).

To select articles that do not have any rows with category_id 54 use a subquery:

```
SELECT 
  a.article_id,
  a.`title`,
  a.`text`,
  a.`date`
FROM `articles` a
WHERE a.`active` = 1 AND
  a.`article_id` not in (
    SELECT c.article_id
    FROM `article_category_reference` c
    WHERE c.`category_id` = 54
  )
ORDER BY a.`date`
DESC
LIMIT 15
```